# Jquery validate engine radio css help

Tags: jquery, css, validation

I am using jquery validate engine plugin. I got the validation right so the challenge is i need to display the radio buttons on line not as a block . Please advice

Comment: So... what does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: <form id="formID" class="formular" method="post" action="">

   <fieldset>
    
       <label>
        <span><b> New City:</b></span>
       
         <input type="radio" name="5" id="5" class="validate[required radio]">
         ewrw 
         <input type="radio" name="5" id="5" class="validate[required radio]">
         Test 
       </label>
      
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;`. That should fix your problem if I'm reading your question correctly.

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS then so I can be more helpful.

Comment: <form id="formID" class="formular" method="post" action=""> <fieldset> <label> <span><b> New City:</b></span> <input type="radio" name="5" id="5" class="validate[required radio]"> ewrw <input type="radio" name="5" id="5" class="validate[required radio]"> Test </label> </form>

Comment: input[type="radio"] {
 display: inline;
}
.formular span.radio, .formular .radio {
 display: inline;
}

Comment: .formular radio {
 display : inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}